# change body background color by clicking btn in javascript

Tags: javascript

I just want to change my body background like toggling whenever i clicked the `btn`, and I want to use the `addEventListener` method.
I'm not sure why my code is not working, it is only working when body `backgroundcolor` is purple.

Here is my code:

```
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.getElementByTagName("body")[0];

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(body.style.backgroundColor = "") {
    body.style.backgroundColor = "purple"
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundColor = ""}
  }
);
```

Comment: This is a classic “where’s the bug” question I’ve seen in interviews.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

1. `getElementByTagName()` should be `getElementsByTagName()`. You have a typo in that method so correct that first.
2. Then you need to use comparison operator (`===`) in `if` condition. Currently you are assigning the value (`=`)

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (body.style.backgroundColor === "") {
    body.style.backgroundColor = "purple"
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundColor = ""
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
Some text
<button>Click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: as we are sure that style object is initailized to " " , it is best practise to use === instead of == . it is advised to avoid == when either side of operands can have [],"",true or false.
unless there is something you are gaining from the coercion here.

Comment: @AyyappaGollu thanks for the suggestion. I addressed that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
     if(document.body.style.backgroundColor=="") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "purple";     
     } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "";
     }
});
```

```html
<body>
color
<button>change</button>
</body>
```